# Angular4 - Best approach AngularCli project or Non Cli project

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

I have been created Angular4 project  using angular cli and working. My doubt is Which one is best approach Cli or non cli project. Whats advantages and disadvantages of these two kind of projects?

Comment: Why would you not use the cli, there are no disadvantages. It helps you to quickly setup components and speeds up your development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Angular CLI makes it easy to create an application that already works, right out of the box. It already follows our best practices!
It is a very powerful tool that goes way beyond the simple bundler or generator.
It has Webpack under the hood, already pre-configured, so you enjoy the benefits without the hassle of configuration.

Pros:
Extremely quick and easy to setup
It comes with a code generator – you can use it to create skeletons of the most common ones (Components, Directives, Services and Pipes) by simply using the cli command ng g .
Webpack, Protractor e2e testing, Karma/Jasmine testing setup automatically
Dependencies pulled in automatically
Centralized configuration via an Angular CLI config file
Quick and easy CLI commands to run the app, create new Components, etc…

Cons:
Less advanced configuration (cannot change advanced Webpackconfig, etc…)
More rigid configuration structure (harder to move config files to desired locations, they’re more strewn about inside of various different directories)
Less or no support for various addons (HTML template engines like PugJS, etc…)

For a manual setup, the pros and cons are effectively the exact opposite of the pros and cons for using the Angular CLI

Pros:
over a few of the main benefits:
Advanced Webpack configuration
Ability to use HTML template engines (due to advanced Webpackconfig)
Cleaner config file and directory structure
Greater flexibility (also due to advanced config)

Cons:
Difficulty of setting up effective unit and e2e testing
Ability to alter advanced config makes for easier configuration mistakes

Comment: `Angular CLI` is more flexible and it also provide the ability to `eject` the `webpack configuration` so that you can modify your configuration as according. I recommend to go for the Angular cli.